# Restriction (or trace) in the style of "Probability Theory", by Klenke

Tags: math-mode

I have searched for "restriction" on this site, but I didn't see any information that answers my particular question.

I am reading the textbook *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* by Klenke, and I am unsure how to reproduce the notation for a function restriction, or the trace of a class of sets.

I am using `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`, along with `amsmath`, `amsthm`, `amssymb`, and a bunch of other (hopefully unrelated) packages.

Below, I've included several examples from the textbook.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would advice against it. Note in your example that the low construction causes some extra line spread. Not good.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mitigate the bad effect such deep symbols have on interline spacing by not specifying the set as a subscript to the bar, but lowering it so its bottom is level with the bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}

\newcommand{\krestr}[1]{%
  \sbox{0}{\raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A-\height\relax}{$\big|$}}%
  \usebox{0}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp0+\depth\relax}{$\scriptstyle#1$}%
}

\newcommand{\cA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{definition}{72}

\begin{definition}
Let $(\varOmega,\cA,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\varOmega'\in\cA$.
On the trace $\sigma$\nobreakdash-algebra $\cA\krestr{\varOmega'}$ we define
a measure by
\begin{equation*}
\mu\krestr{\varOmega'}(A)\coloneqq \mu(A)
\qquad \text{for $A\in\cA$ with $A\subset\varOmega'$}
\end{equation*}
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
The restriction of the Lebesgue-Borel measure on $\bigl(\RR,\cB(\RR)\bigr)$
to $[0,1]$ is a probability measure on $([0,1],\cB(\RR)\krestr{[0,1]})$.
More generally, for a measurable $A\in\cB(\RR)$, we call the restriction
$\lambda\krestr{A}$ the \emph{Lebesgue measure} on~$A$. Often this measure
will be denoted by the same symbol~$\lambda$ when there is no danger of
ambiguity.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `$|$` instead of `$\big|$` we'd get

[image]

As you see, the symbol is as clear and lines are correctly spaced.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

I would echo the thought @mickep has expressed in a comment, that the very low-seated conditioning characters/symbols will likely require an increase in inter-line spacing. This may (or may not) be undesirable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \raisebox and \scalebox macros
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} 
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\newcommand\Restr[1]{%
   % scale the vertical bar 15% vertically and 5% horizontally:
   \raisebox{-0.35ex}{$\scalebox{1.05}[1.15]{$\vert$}%
                      _{\scriptscriptstyle #1\mathstrut}$}}

\begin{document}
\dots\ the restriction $f\Restr{C}$ of $f$ to $C$ is \dots

\dots\ on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \Restr{[0,1]})$. More \dots

\dots\ the restriction $\lambda\Restr{A}$ the \emph{Lebesgue} \dots

\dots\ \em on the trace $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\Restr{\Omega'}$, we \dots
\end{document}
```